# How to allow visitors to upload images directly to Google Cloud Storage

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-cloud-storage

How can I store images in Google Cloud Storage and display them on my website instead of keeping the image in a folder on my websites with CodeIgniter?

Currently files are upload to my sever first but I want visitors to upload them without involving my website as intermediate:

```
function file_up($name, $type, $id, $multi = '', $no_thumb = '', $ext = '.jpg')
    {
        if ($multi == '') {
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$name]['tmp_name'], 'uploads/' . $type . '_image/' . $type . '_' . $id . $ext);
            if ($no_thumb == '') {
                $this->crud_model->img_thumb($type, $id, $ext);
            }
        } elseif ($multi == 'multi') {
            $ib = 1;
            foreach ($_FILES[$name]['name'] as $i => $row) {
                $ib = $this->file_exist_ret($type, $id, $ib);
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$name]['tmp_name'][$i], 'uploads/' . $type . '_image/' . $type . '_' . $id . '_' . $ib . $ext);
                if ($no_thumb == '') {
                    $this->crud_model->img_thumb($type, $id . '_' . $ib, $ext);
                }
            }
        }
```

I have checked the documentation but it wasn't clear.

Comment: i will appreciate if i can get a sample code.......i have gone through it..there is less support for php..

Answer (score 0):

Try any of these services. Firebase Storage, GCP Bucket or Cloudinary.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/buckets

https://cloudinary.com/

Comment: am  very new to this.. am using codeigniter is not vey clear to me

Answer (score 0):

Allowing users to upload files directly to Cloud Storage is the most cost-effective option that would improve uploading speed, overall reliability and reduce the workload on the servers.

There is an official documentation page with [the instructions](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/googlestorage/user_upload) on how to do that. The process will generally follow this steps:

1. Your application will create a URL for uploading the file using the following command:

`$upload_url = CloudStorageTools::createUploadUrl('/upload/handler', $options);`

2. User can begin uploading within 10 minute of URL's creation.
3. After the upload finishes a POST request will be sent from Google to `'/upload/handler'`, or any other handler you specify, with the content that looks like this:

```
    array(1) {
      ['uploaded_files']=>
      array(5) {
        ['name']=>    string(14) 'hello.txt'
        ['type']=>    string(10) 'text/plain'
        ['tmp_name']=>    string(73) 'gs://my_bucket/L2FwcHMtdXBsb2FkL2Jsb2JzL2IxNUFBVGNJNXNTd0VqR0tFSUtDRGxadGc'
        ['error']=>    int(0)
        ['size']=>    int(1452)
      }
    }
```